# Laravel upload file form not working

Tags: php, file, upload, laravel-5

It seems that my file upload is not working. Functions of the file [e.g $file->getOriginalExtension();] are returning errors.

Here's my view:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="/project/file_post.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <---other text inputs--->
    Photo: <input type="file" name="photo"  />

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-inline" value="SAVE ">

</form>
```

Controller:

```
//code below returns only the filename
$input = Input::all();
$file = array_get($input,'photo');
print_r($file);

//but when using this..it returns an error
$extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

DD($input) returns:

```
array:8 [▼
  "_token" => "6eScEZe1SLL72JDrQjmBJllNyiHaT8hdGKKMtjsD"
  "photo" => "test_test_2016.jpg"
  "field2" => "test"
  "field3" => "test"
  "field4" => "test"
  "field5" => "test"
  "field6" => "test"
  "field7" => "test"
]
```

Am I doing something wrong? It returns the filename of the file but when using the functions, it's returning all sorts of error (e.g Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string)

Can you please help? Thanks!

Addendum:

```
$photo = $request->file('photo');
echo $photo;
```

Code above also doesn't work. No errors. Only returns blank.

Comment: add form `action="post_page.php";`  i think its missing from your code. change the page address which the code run after submitting form.

Comment: @JeesKDenny, I forgot to put it in my post but it's not missing on my actual code.

Comment: can't you directly use like this? $name = Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request `$request` worked for me.

```
if($request->hasFile('photo')) {
   $photoExt = $request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of laravel you need to use Input::file so use something like this instead in your controller

```
if (Input::hasFile('photo')) {
    $photoFile = Input::file('photo');
    $extension = $photoFile->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
}
```